# Семантика объявлений 2D-массивов в Си

Tags: c

Не могу понять семантику следующего выражение на Си:

```
char (*daytab)[13]
```

Оно эквивалентно такому выражению:

```
char daytab[2][13]
```

В первом выражении сообщается, что так объявленный параметр функции - указатель на массив из 13 элементов. Наличие круглых скобок здесь обязательно, потому что квадратные скобки [] имеют больший приоритет, чем знак ссылки *. Без скобок это было бы объявление массива из 13 указателей на данные типа char:

```
char daytab[13]
```

Объясните, что происходит в первом определении? Подобные конструкции под капотом, как правило, выглядят очень просто: как работа с каким-нибудь регистром EDI, а понять семантику таких выражений бывает нелегко.

Если разбирать первый пример по частям справа налево, то можно попытаться объяснить это так:

1. объявляется массив из 13 элементов
2. Слева находится тип данных, хранящихся в массиве
3. типа данных char (*daytab) не поддается человеческой интерпретации, и здесь я застопорился

Помогите разобраться

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В с/с++ не разбирают справа-налево. А разбирают по [спирали](https://habrahabr.ru/post/100104/). Вот есть чудесный сервис - http://www.cdecl.org/ , который помогает парсить подобые вещи.

Answer (score 1):

Если быть точнее, оно эквивалентно такому выражению: `char daytab[ ][13]`. А начинать надо со скобок, а не справа: указатель на массив из 13 элементов типа char. В общем-то KoVadim все нужное и так написал.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку формально все уже рассказали, рискну немного развлечь...

```
// попробуем исследовать эту загадку с помощью gcc компилятора

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

// начнем строить предположения, отталкиваясь от уже имеющихся знаний
// и проверять их, пытаясь скомпилировать код, который будем потихоньку писать
int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  // хотя бы скомпилиться?
  char (*dtime)[26];  // OK я взял 26 с целью использовать далее ctime()
  // пойдем последовательно
  // судя по звездочке в скобках dtime похоже указатель,
  // а [] говорят, что он указывает на массив, очевидно из char-ов
  // проверим...
  printf("sizeof(d) : %ld  sizeof(*d) : %ld\n", 
         sizeof(dtime), sizeof(*dtime));
  // ага, сама переменная занимет 8 байт на X86-64, 
  // это подтверждает предположение, что это указатель
  // и указывает он на область памяти размером 26 * sizeof(char) 

  // при таком раскладе память под массив никто за нас не выделит
  dtime = (typeof(dtime))malloc(sizeof(*dtime)); 
  // а приводим тип для g++ (вдруг кто-то его очень любит)
  // (бредовый компайлер, не верит, что void * такой же адрес, как и цель)

  // теперь посмотрим как можно обращаться с переменной этого "типа"
  time_t t = time(0);
  // память на которую указывает dtime ведет себя как nil-terminated string?
  ctime_r(&t, dtime[0]);
  puts(strlen(*dtime) < 26 ? "размерчик угадали" : "оппа... портим память");

  // распечатаем посимвольно
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(*dtime); i++)
    putchar((*dtime)[i]);

  free(dtime); // valgrind утверждает, что с heap все OK

  return puts("End") == EOF; // и закончим, вернув 0 (я надеюсь, что терминал не сломан)
}
```

@typemoon,  и где Вы такие штучки  находите?

Comment: "и где Вы такие штучки находите" Почитайте книгу Эриксона "Хакинг, искусство эксплоита", там есть вещи и поинтереснее. Например, в самом начале использование переменной unsigned int для хранения адреса вместо использования указателей позволило немного сократить количество скобок и звездочек.

Comment: Хотя мой пример не оттуда, а из Кернигана и Ритчи.

Comment: @typemoon, интересуетесь играми с указателями? Если интересно, посмотрите часть кода хэш-таблицы символов калькулятра -- http://pastebin.com/yqAA1mM6

Comment: @typemoon, кстати, а почему вопрос о 2-D массивах? Ведь в коде вопроса их нет. Есть указатель на одномерный массив.

Comment: Просто этот пример из главы про двумерные массивы.